# Location of first null off boresight, in ant pattern of 2 element phased array antenna, in radians as a function of wavelength and distance?

Tags: radar

Does it make sense that the first null off boresight of a 2-element phased array antenna, where each element is isotropic, in-phase, and separated by a distance $d$ (where $d$ is much greater than the wavelength) occurs at an angle $\theta = \lambda/(2\cdot d)$?

[image: Is there an easier way to understand this?]

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to type out screenshots or images of text; for formulae, one can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: Ok, good to know. I will going forward. Thank you for the help.

Comment: yes, it is correct